# Would adding "identity" permission to google chrome extension manifest trigger a user warning on extension update?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I haven't found any info about security implications of adding "identity" permission to chrome extension manifest. It is not mentioned in the list of permissions that will cause a warning ( https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permission_warnings#warnings ), but also it is not listed in the list of permissions that wouldn't trigger a user warning ( https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permission_warnings#nowarning )

I would also consider adding it as an "optional_permission", but it is also not included in the optional permissions list: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions

Comment: Check the permissions of the unpacked version.

Comment: FWIW Running chrome.management.getPermissionWarningsByManifest(prompt(), console.log) and pasting a random manifest.json contents with "identity" permission doesn't produce any warning for this API.

Comment: So, did it cause a warning?.. I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @bruddah  It didn't.

Comment: @mechatroner Sweet, thanks!